# Opentsdb open source time series database

Tags: database, time-series, opentsdb

Is there anyone who has installed opentsdb on Ubuntu 15.04 version? If so please share the steps to be followed. I tried number of times but I am not able to install it properly.

Comment: It is same step as mention in the opentsdb website. Could you paste your error.

Comment: Vicky I got my error resolved. If I want to save some data in tsdb (similar to that of mysql using http url's) and fetch it and display some graphs...Is it possible? If so can you please share the details

Answer (score 0):

You need to write tcollector, for example:

**Step 1:** create metrics:

```
./tsdb mkmetric proc.loadavg.1m proc.loadavg.5m
```

**Step 2:** create collector in shell script or command line.

```
cat >loadavg-collector.sh <<\EOF
#!/bin/bash set -e 
 while true; do   
 awk -v now=`date +%s` -v host=`hostname` \   '{ print "put proc.loadavg.1m " now " " $1 " host=" host;
 print "put proc.loadavg.5m " now " " $2 " host=" host }'
  /proc/loadavg   sleep 15 done | nc -w 30 host.name.of.tsd PORT EOF
```

Then:

```
chmod +x loadavg-collector.sh 

nohup ./loadavg-collector.sh &
```

It will collect data every 15 second on metrics proc.loadavg.1m and proc.loadavg.5m. Now you will be able to see graph in webinterface of opentsdb.

For detail please check the link below:
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/quickstart.html

Comment: Vicky, Let us suppose I have a webservice. I will save the webservice response in mySQL. Ihis is what I am doing till now. Now I want to know how can I save the webservice response in opentsdb instead of mySQL. Please give some idea...I am newbie to opentsdb.

Comment: Yes you can do it. You need to write a script that will push/put your webservice responses into OpenTSDB instead of mysql.  It is samething what you do with MySQL. when you say insert into table in mysql, you need to change that line and say print "put proc.loadavg.5m " now " " value" host=" host.

Comment: you mean to say I have to write a  collector using python script which will store my data in tsdb?Can you please share a sample...